# Find the vertical offset of an object within a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, grid

I have a various number of `Grid`s within a `ListBox`, and I need to find the vertical offset from the top of the `ListBox` of that particular `Grid` when tapped.

Thanks for the help.